# ScrollView on Android not rendering after resize

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Create simple chat

```
<Page
 actionBarHidden="true"
> 
 <GridLayout columns="*" rows="1*,8*,1*">
  <StackLayout row="0" class="form"  background="#FAE379" >
   <Label class="lbl-menu" fontSize="20" marginBottom="1%" @tap="$navigateBack">
    <FormattedString>
     <Span fontSize="15">{{'fa-chevron-left' | fonticon}}</Span>
     <Span fontSize="20" class="txt-btn">     Test</Span>
    </FormattedString>
   </Label>
  </StackLayout>

  <ScrollView  row ="1" id="myScroller">
   <StackLayout >
    <StackLayout v-for="(m,i) in messages" :key="i" marginTop="30">
     <StackLayout class="card-chat-msg-o" v-if="m.u">
      <StackLayout>
       <Label class="card-chat-text-o"  textWrap="true" :text="m.txt"/>
      </StackLayout>
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout class="card-chat-msg-u" v-else>
      <StackLayout>
       <Label class="card-chat-text-u"  textWrap="true" :text="m.txt"/>
      </StackLayout>
     </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
   </StackLayout >
  </ScrollView  >

  <GridLayout row ="2" columns="1*,8*,1*" rows="*" borderColor="#F1F1F1" borderWidth="2%">
   <Label col="0" class="fa" fontSize="30">{{'fa-paperclip' | fonticon}}</Label>
   <TextView col="1" editable="true" v-model="message" hint="Enter message" autocorrect="true"/>
   <Label col="2" class="fa" fontSize="30" @tap="sendMessage()">{{'fa-play' | fonticon}}</Label>
  </GridLayout>

 </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

when I focus TextView , android show keyboard, ScrollView partially overlaped and bottom items of messages not showing

after that I push new items in messages

ScrollView  rennder only new messages in correct positions other items of messages not showing

https://yadi.sk/i/R7F7sELLYZAREw

ListView also has a similar problem

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=5jP4yP

Comment: Are you using Vue? Can you build a Playground example of same?

Comment: Yes, I use Vue. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=5jP4yP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have problem with your layouts, seems to me that you got too many nested layouts. I have built a similar [example here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=xHcmGb) that should give you what you are looking for with relatively few UI elements on screen.

Apart from nested layout, I would suggest you to

- Avoid percentage based measurements as much as possible. By default all measurements will be in density independent pixels which should work for most use cases.
- ActionBar is usually a fixed element, it will not increase it's size based on screen height. So even if you are placing a custom view, you don't have to keep dynamic height.

Learn more about [layouts here](https://www.nslayouts.com/).

Comment: That was the problem. Thank!